# string comparison in c#

Tags: c#, string

I want to compare two strings and one of them may be a `null` string, am using `StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` feature of C#. This throws an exception in runtime when a `null` string is encountered. What shall I do to be able to compare even `null` strings?

Comment: You can check if they are both empty first with String.IsNullOrEmpty

Comment: What sort of comparison are you performing? Equality or ordering?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As well as the options already given to you, you can consider using `StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` instead. `StringComparer` handles nulls without throwing exceptions:

```
using System;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        StringComparer comparer = StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase;
        Console.WriteLine(comparer.Compare("a", "A"));
        Console.WriteLine(comparer.Compare("a", null));
        Console.WriteLine(comparer.Compare(null, "A"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the string.Compare in Aliostads example below equivalent to using a StringComparer?

Comment: @Fredrik: I don't know, to be honest. You'd hope so, but there could well be subtleties...

Answer (score 3):

use

```
 string.Compare(s1, s2, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
```

benefit of using this is that it will return 0 (equal) if two strings are `null` - which is the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

`if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(yourString)) {
    // If true...
}`

Answer (score 0):

Depens on what do you want to happen when string is null.

You may simply fall back to empty string like this: `(str ?? "").Compare(...)`

Answer (score 0):

This from a post I remember @Jon Skeet answering a question about comparing:

```
string myCompareString = "compare me";

if(myCompareString.Equals(myOtherMaybeNullString, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
{
   // blah blah
}
```

Causes the comparison against a string you know is not null to a string that might be null (unless you are comparing 2 potentially null strings).

Answer (score 0):

Just as a extra option String.Equals handles null so you could also use:

using System;

```
class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
            var a = String.Equals("test", "Test", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
            var b = String.Equals("test", null, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
            var c = String.Equals(null, "Test", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
            var d = String.Equals(null, null, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
    }
}
```